# Angular UI Bootstrap Pagination Server side?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I would like to implement server side pagination for angular-ui bootstrap pagination. I will be using scope.items in ng-repeat to display a table listing and initially fetch 50 items from server and store in scope.items object. Then i would fetch next 50 items when the scope.currentPage is 3 and so on. The problem is that i would like to keep the scope.items as it contains always 50 items. So when i get the next 50 items i need to start form  3rd page. But the pagination is not working properly.

Please suggest a method to implement this.

In html page.

```
  <pagination first-text="First" items-per-page="pageSize" last-text="Last" ng-change="pageChanged()" max-size="paginationMaxSize" next-text="›" ng-model="currentPage" previous-text="‹" total-items="total_items_count">
</pagination>
```

In ng-repeat we are using

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in items|startFrom:(CurrentPage - 1) * pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" ng-show="items.length">                                                      <td><span>{{item.name}}                                                       </span></td></tr>
```

Comment: How is this server call being made and what information are you passing to let it know what data to serve? (url params / json payload / etc)

Comment: @Dreamlines . We are returing json array from server. Please check the updated question